# Faster execution of Vanilla Swaps in Python in Quantlib

Tags: python, quantlib

I am trying to price a Vanilla Swap in Quantlib for multiple ccys and settlement dates across thousands of curves for a thousand different instruments. I am trying to find a way on how to essentially scale my code.

I am using the Python library and using the multiprocessing component did help performance a little. Since a a lot of the curves and trades will be reused again and again, I am trying to find out if there is a way to disable some default settings which will help improve performance.
Instead of pricing swaps swaps individually, is there way to aggregate them and calculate the NPV like adding them to a portfolio?
Also, I read a few posts around disabling notifications for observers but I can't see to find how to update the settings for this. Not sure if this will be helpful or cause more problems.

I am also posting a code snippet below in case there is something obvious which I can change to make the code run faster. (I have only kept 2 data points and removed multiprocessing component from code below for brevity)

```
import QuantLib as ql

execution_date = ql.Date(10, 9, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = execution_date
periods = ['1D', '50Y', ]
market_rates = [-0.0043, 0.002140, ]
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
trade_count = 100
scenarios = 100
num = 0.000001

curves = []
for _ in range(scenarios):
    swap_rate_helpers = []
    for i in range(len(market_rates)):
        market_rate = market_rates[i] + num
        quote = ql.SimpleQuote(market_rate)
        helper = ql.SwapRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(quote),
                                   ql.Period(periods[i]),
                                   calendar,
                                   ql.Annual,
                                   ql.Unadjusted,
                                   ql.Actual360(),
                                   ql.Euribor6M()
                                   )
        swap_rate_helpers.append(helper)

    curve = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(execution_date, swap_rate_helpers, ql.Actual360())
    curves.append(curve)
    num += 0.000001

start_date = calendar.advance(execution_date, 2, ql.Days)
end_date = calendar.advance(start_date, 30, ql.Years)

fixed_schedule = ql.Schedule(start_date, end_date, ql.Period(12, ql.Months), calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)
float_schedule = ql.Schedule(start_date, end_date, ql.Period(6, ql.Months), calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.ModifiedFollowing, ql.DateGeneration.Forward, False)

term_structure = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(curves[0])
float_index = ql.Euribor6M(term_structure)
swaps = []
swap_engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(term_structure)
for _ in range(trade_count):
    ir_swap = ql.VanillaSwap(ql.VanillaSwap.Payer, 100000000, fixed_schedule, 0.008, ql.Actual360(), float_schedule, float_index, 0, ql.Actual360())
    ir_swap.setPricingEngine(swap_engine)
    swaps.append(ir_swap)

for curve in curves:
    term_structure.linkTo(curve)
    for swap in swaps:
        swap.NPV()

print 'Trade Count: {0}'.format(trade_count)
print 'Swaps Priced: {0}'.format(scenarios)
```

Comment: Why do you have 100 scenarios?

Comment: In the code snippet I posted, I kept it as 100 so the code can execute in due time as 1000 takes a while but for my use case, I would need to run this across a 1000 scenarios.

Comment: But it doesn't appear that any scenarios are stochastic. You are merely adding 1/100th of a basis point to each scenario. Why is this step even necessary?  Obviously, it increases the run time by 100x.

Comment: This is just for sampling reasons for now but to your point, yes it will either be a stochastic measure or a set of predefined curves scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with regards to enabling and disabling notifications, there are methods available on the `ObservableSettings` C++ class:

```cpp
QuantLib::ObservableSettings::instance().disableUpdates(true);

    // do the setup

QuantLib::ObservableSettings::instance().enableUpdates();
```

Hopefully these have been exported through to the python bindings. However, I am not entirely sure this will make a significant difference to your performance. See the original post for this feature on this regard [1].

[1] https://sourceforge.net/p/quantlib/mailman/message/31650848/